# How do I define the below into a function? As I need to use the same code 4 times

Tags: python-3.x

```
 f = open("airport.csv" ,encoding='utf-8')
    Origin = input('Please Enter your origin of assigned airport code')     
for row in csv.reader(f):
    if row[4] == Origin.upper():
          print(row[6], row[7])
          lat1=float(row[6])
          lon1=float(row[7])
          code1=row[4]
f.close()
```

I am unsure of how to make it a function

Comment: The first step would be getting the indentation right so that it functions as straight-line code. If it doesn't work outside a function, it's not going to work inside a function, either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following that get the file name and returns `lat1,lon1,code1` within a tuple :

```
def func(filename):
    Origin = input('Please Enter your origin of assigned airport code')
    with open("{}.csv".format(filename) ,encoding='utf-8') as f:   
      for row in csv.reader(f):
        if row[4] == Origin.upper():
              print(row[6], row[7])
              lat1=float(row[6])
              lon1=float(row[7])
              code1=row[4]
    return lat1,lon1,code1
```

Comment: When did Niklaus Wirth get memorialized in Python keyword form? I suspect you meant `with open(...)`...

Comment: @twalberg Yep fixed ;)